# latex table of contents chapter and subtitles separated

Tags: table-of-contents, alignment

I have a table of contents that is a little bit long. It covers two pages. One chapter head is seperated from it's subchapters and I don't know how to keep them together because according to the thesis format chapter headers and their sub-chapters shouldn't be sepearated.

My table of contents right now;
[image]

I want Materials and Methodology chapter beginning to go to the next page. Is there a simple way to achieve this in LAtex or am I have to use a pdf editor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
...
\addtocontents{toc}{\newpage}
\chapter{Materials and Methodology}
...
```

which will put a `\newpage` into the ToC just before the chapter title. You could use `\clearpage` instead of `\newpage` and possibly have to put `\protect` just before like:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}
```

but this is only required if `\newpage` is *fragile*.